# How to change button look based on how many times it was pressed?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, button

Im very new to the android and im stuck at this. Ive been trying to figure out how to dynamically change the look of a button based on how many times it was pressed. There are total 4 states, and they loop back to the first state. [This is how the 4 states look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FK8v.png) Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: These states, are they a simply an image you want to put on the button?, Also when you say "based on how many times it was pressed", do you mean on the current app run or even if the app was closed then it should remember the amount of times it was pressed?

Comment: Okay so later I will be adding a way to dynamically change the width and height of the button so Im not sure if an image is the right way to do it, Id prefer if it was scalable graphic like a vector. The app should remember in which state it was though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is declare a `variable` which stores the number of `Button` clicks, and for each number of `Button` clicks you increment the count and change the `background resource` of the `Button` as such:

```
int buttonClickCount = 0;

Button button = findViewById(//ID of button);

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                buttonClickCount++;
                if(buttonCount == 1)
                    mButton.setBackgroundResource(//background resource for image 1);
                else if(buttonCount ==2)
                    mButton.setBackgroundResource(//background resource for image 2);
        //continue the rest
            }
        });
```